# Printing how many attempts a Brute Force Hack Takes

Tags: python, passwords, brute-force

As part of an assignment we have to stimulate a Brute Force Hack to analyse the Mathematics of a Password Policy. Currently I have code where a 4 digit Pin is inputted and the code randomly inputs possible combinations until the set pin code is found. After this it displays the time the process took, however I also want it to display the amount of guesses it takes to crack the password. The code i currently have keeps printing the inputted password instead of the amount of guesses taken.

```
import time 
start = time.process_time()
import random
number = int(input("Input a number that is a password: "))
guess = 0

while (guess != number):
    guess = random.randint(0000,9999)
    print(guess)

print("Your Password is " + str(number))
print("The Brute Force Took: ")
print(time.process_time() - start)
print("The Brute Force Guessed the Password in: ")
print(str(guess))
```

I don't currently study code as this is for a math assignment, however I am very new to it and do wish to pursue it as a hobby, if anyone could please help me with this problem on how to print the amount of guesses the code takes that would be awesome!

Comment: Increment a counter variable in the loop.

Comment: Why are you using random guesses? Why not just `for guess in range(10000):`? Then the number of attempts will be equal to `guess+1`. Your method will sometimes repeat the same guess, but a sequential scan won't.

Comment: Initialize `num_guesses = 1` before the loop, and do `num_guesses += 1` inside the loop.

Comment: As part of the criteria it was outlined that randomness was to be explored, i first used sequential guessing but was then told to redo the assignment. How exactly would i implement a counter variable?

Comment: Read my last comment, I explained it. If you're advanced enough to be exploring cryptography and hacking, this should be really basic.

Comment: Thanks man, i implemented it into the loop and now its working, this assignment has opened up code to me and i hope to continue exploring it

Answer (score 0):

```py
import time 
start = time.process_time()
import random
number = int(input("Input a number that is a password: "))
guess = 0
guesses = 0
while (guess != number):
    guess = random.randint(0000,9999)
    print(guess)
    guesses = guesses+1

print("Your Password is " + str(number))
print("The Brute Force Took: ")
print(time.process_time() - start)
print(f"The Brute Force Guessed the Password in: {guesses}  ")
```

if you need anymore info just comment and I will help :)